# How to find the non singular condition for this equation

Tags: special-functions

I'm trying to solve this one dimensional time-independent Schrodinger equation:

$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+V(x)\psi=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}\psi
$$

where

$$
V(x)=-\frac{\hbar^2b}{m}sech^2(a x)
$$

,$k$ is a parameter, $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers.

It has the general solution in this form

$$
\psi(x)=C_1*P_{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+8 b}-a}{2 a}}^{\frac{k}{a}}(\tanh  (a x))+C_2* Q_{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+8 b}-a}{2 a}}^{\frac{k}{a}}(\tanh  (a x))
$$

where $P^\mu_\lambda$ and $Q^\mu_\lambda$ are the associate Legendre polynomials, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants determined by the boundary condition.

Now I want to determine the eigenstates, which requires the wave function $\psi(x)$ is finite every where. This will give a restriction on $k$ to certain discrete values. And I have problem finding the $k's$.

Mathematically, this is equivalent to find the $k's$ that makes the associate Legendre polynomials finite on range $-1\leq x\leq1$:

$$
P_{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+8 b}-a}{2 a}}^{\frac{k}{a}}(x)
$$
$$
Q_{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+8 b}-a}{2 a}}^{\frac{k}{a}}(x)
$$

So what are the $k's$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ that makes the above associate Legendre polynomials finite?

Comment: Hint: This is just as simple as continuing the process.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it, what do you mean by "continuing the process"?